# Compiling Java project on command line with CPlex

Tags: command-line, java, compiling

I'm trying to compile a java project that uses CPlex on the command line (Ubuntu 14.04). I'm trying to run this command:

```
javac -cp /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community128/cplex/lib/cplex.jar *.java
```

I get about 98 errors and I believe they are all stemming from the first one:

```
error: package ilog.concert does not exist
```

I think this error means that the compiler can't find CPlex packages. I'm 100% sure that CPlex is installed here: /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community128/cplex

What should I try? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command I needed was

```
javac -classpath .:/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community128/cplex/lib/cplex.jar *.java
```

See the javac documentation for more info: http://www.cs.yorku.ca/tech/other/java/docs/tooldocs/solaris/javac.html (I should have checked this out earlier :O).

The `.:` at the beginning of the path allows me to include my current directory as well.